# Debian Bullseye: package dependencies libc6-dev

Tags: debian, apt

I have bought a Zimaboard and wanted to install the following packages:

```
sudo apt install make libssl-dev libghc-zlib-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libexpat1-dev gettext unzip
```

I receive the following error about unmet dependencies:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-13+deb11u6) but 2.37-5 is to be installed
             Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.31-13+deb11u6) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

First I thought I broke something, so I factory-resetted the board to a plain installation, but the error persisted. I found solutions that recommend installing gcc-9, but gcc-10 is already installed and gcc-11 ultimately borks with the same dependency problem

Ultimately I wanted to compile git for this system

*Update 1:*

I disabled testing and ran `apt update`:

```
apt update
Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
Get:2 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/shells:/fish:/release:/3/Debian_11  InRelease [1,556 B]
Hit:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
Hit:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bullseye InRelease
Get:5 https://pkgs.tailscale.com/stable/debian bullseye InRelease
```

Still the same error

Comment: `apt update` first. You've mixed sid repos with bullseye.

Comment: 2.37-5 is from testing/unstable not bullseye (nor bookworm). Check what this means: https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian . Also why build git when it's packaged?

Comment: @A.B I want git 2.40.1 for compatibility with our processes

Comment: Have removed the testing sources, ran apt update, but still no success

Comment: @Sascha: You've made a FrankenDebian which is strongly not recommended.Use deb.debian.org only.

Comment: Tailscale/OpenSuSE are the recommended ways to install that software, the docker one follows also the recommendation (and was already in that way after installing from the CasaOS thing which is based on Debian)